# Discovering open port range in remote host using powershell

Tags: powershell, networking

How can we check if a given host has any open port using powershell?

Test-NetConnection can be used in a loop, but is there a faster and more practical way to check a large range of ports?

```
Test-NetConnection ###.###.###.### -Port ##
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection)
supports targeting only *one* computer and port at a time.

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you could use
[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel`
to target multiple ports *in parallel* threads to speed up the operation; e.g.:

```bash
, 21 + 80..88 + 8080 | 
   ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 32 -Parallel { 
     Test-NetConnection  127.0.0.1 -Port $_ 
   }
```

- `, 21 + 80..88 + 8080` is a sample array of port numbers, and shows mixing a single number with a *range* (`..`) of port numbers; the `,` before `21` is necessary to ensure that the single number is wrapped in an array, which ensures that `+` performs *array concatenation*.
- `-ThrottleLimit` determines how many threads may be active at a time (the default is `5`); while it often makes sense not to
  exceed the number of available CPU cores, in *network*-bound operations such as in the case at hand, the number can be higher,
  and `32` is the default in *remoting* operations (when using `Invoke-Command -ComputerName`).